# How do I install hardware driver using C++ on Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, drivers

How do I install a hardware driver (**inf file**) using C++?

Platform : **Win32**

Comment: You don't write C++ code, you write an inf file.  The format is well documented, try typing more than one line of text in your question.

Comment: @nobugz: actually, there's more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is usually called *pre-installation*. (The normal install process is triggered by the arrival of an hardware device.)

The relevant functions can be found in `<DIFxAPI.h>` from the DDK. You probably want to call `DriverPackageInstall()`. The expected return value is `ERROR_NO_SUCH_DEVINST` [sic] as there won't be such a device yet.

There's some 64 bit funkyness: you can't install a 64 bits driver from a Win32 app (at least not in XP/Vista/Windows7/2003/2008). Hence, your Win32 installer must check if `DriverPackageInstall()` returns `ERROR_IN_WOW64` and then call `CreateProcess` to start your 64 bits installer.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at using the InstallHinfSection function, in the setupapi.dll.  Here's the related docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376957%28VS.85%29.aspx